# Is it possible to search all databases in a SQL Server for a specific view? If yes how?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, information-schema

I am trying to find a specific view. I know it exists on a specific SQL Server but I don't know under which Database. If I use Information_Schema it would only search within the current Database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v 
WHERE v.Table_Name LIKE '%vwViewName%'
```

Is it possible to search all databases in a SQL Server instance for a specific view? If yes, then how?

Comment: You could use dynamic sql, you could just run that query on each database, you could use SQL Search (a free tool from Redgate), you could....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sp_msforeachdb` to check `sys.views` across all databases:

```
    DECLARE @views TABLE (ViewName NVARCHAR(4000))
    DECLARE @ViewName NVARCHAR(4000) = 'ViewName'
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT ''?'' + ''.'' + s.name + ''.'' + v.name from [?].sys.views v inner join sys.schemas s on v.schema_id=s.schema_id WHERE v.name LIKE ''%' + @ViewName + '%'''

    INSERT INTO @views (ViewName)
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @query

    SELECT  * 
    FROM    @views
```

Comment: Please don't use this undocumented, unsupported, and buggy system procedure. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: Marc, do you own stock of this product :)

Comment: @GuidoG: no - just a very happy user of it :-))

Answer (score 1):

you can build a list to search for the view in each database like this

```
SELECT 'select * from ' + name + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like ''%vwViewName%''' 
FROM   master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

this will return a result like this for example

```
select * from master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%' 
select * from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%' 
select * from model.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'  
select * from msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'   
select * from Test.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'   
select * from Prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'   
select * from sysdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'
```

Then you can run each of these queries

you can offcourse filter out tempdb and other databases.
Also, if you want only run one query then use union like this

```
select table_catalog + '.' + table_schema + '.' + table_name  from test.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'
union all   
select table_catalog + '.' + table_schema + '.' + table_name  from prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views v where  v.Table_Name like '%vwViewName%'
```

now you have only one query to run and still get all databases where the view is found and the result will be in format `DBName.dbo.ViewName`

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG for the solution but Horia's query gives me the exact result like DBName.dbo.ViewName. Also, it returns multiple results if the viewName exists in multiple Databases.

Comment: No problem. That is the beauty of stack overflow, you can choose from more than one answer. I also edited my answer to just one query to run which will return also multiple results if the viewName exists in multiple databases.